# Java Server - Sending packets out incorrectly?

Tags: java, tcp, packet, outputstream

Currently have a TCP server built in Java and I'm sending messages/packets out to clients using their socket's OutputStream:

```
// Send all player's information to everyone else
outerPlayerIter = players.iterator();
while(outerPlayerIter.hasNext()) {
    Player outerPlayer = outerPlayerIter.next();
       
    Iterator<Player> innerPlayerIter = players.iterator();
    while(innerPlayerIter.hasNext()) {
        Player innerPlayer = innerPlayerIter.next();
        boolean isYou = false;
        if(innerPlayer.equals(outerPlayer)) isYou = true;
        // Send innerPlayer's info to outerPlayer
        Thread.sleep(100);
        dataBuffer.clearBuffer();
        dataBuffer.writeByte(Msgs.mm_toclient.MES_SENDPLAYERINFO);
        dataBuffer.writeBool(isYou);
        dataBuffer.writeBool(innerPlayer.getIsHost());
        dataBuffer.writeString(innerPlayer.getName());
        dataBuffer.writeString(innerPlayer.getPublicIP().getHostAddress());
        dataBuffer.writeShort((short)innerPlayer.getUdpPort());
        outerPlayer.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(dataBuffer.getByteArray());
        outerPlayer.getSocket().getOutputStream().flush();
    }
   
}
```

However, sometimes the clients don't appear to receive all the messages. I can't send multiple messages at the exact same time over one socket.

One way to temporarily fix this was to sleep before I send another packet out. But I'm not sure why this is needed.

Am I doing something wrong in regards to how I'm sending/writing the packets out to be sent? What can be fixed to allow multiple packets to be received correctly at once without sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the fact that the client closes the socket way too fast before the communication should actually finished. Could you please try to bump up the thread.sleep value or, on the client side, if you use any kind of timing, try to bump up that one as well.

Comment: I found out that my TCP client (GameMaker) sometimes will read multiple messages in each Async Network event. Each "message" I send from the Java server is 256 bytes. If I sleep a significant amount of time between each message write to the outputstream, GameMaker will only see 256 bytes per event. If I don't sleep, sometimes it will receive multiple messages at a time in one event (512 bytes for example instead of 256). And I can't tell if this is GameMaker's fault or Java's. I'd rather deal with one message at a time instead of parsing. Is there a way to do this or tell what's causing this?

Comment: Well, it appears GameMaker is at fault and is concatenating multiple packets in one event. I have to manually parse through the messages and determine where a new message/packet starts in the buffer while reading it.